# Why my Graphics card is disabled after installing Ubuntu Gnome 14.04LTS?

Tags: 14.04

Hello I installed Ubuntu Gnome 14.04LTS then after installation I found out that my Graphics Card is disabled. Why? Im on a hybrid machine with IntelCore i3 and AMD RADEON Graphics card. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your graphics card is not disabled. Rather you are on Generic Xorg Display drivers. You need to install the proprietary AMD drivers to be able to use your AMD Graphics card.

You can search for `additional drivers` in applications. And enable the drivers suitable for your Graphics cards. And if the Drivers support hybrid configuation, you should be freely able to switch between your Intel HD and Radeon chipsets.

If the above method doesn't let you control the hybrid configuration, [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD#Manually_installing_Catalyst_13.4.2C_special_case_for_Intel.2BAC8-AMD_hybrid_graphics) has a manual way of installing drivers in order to control the hybrid chipset.

Comment: Can you advise me if should I need to activate AMD Graphics card or I will stick on Generic Xorg under Intel?

Comment: In my opinion, you should definitely activate the AMD drivers for your PC's optimal performance and the AMD drivers would be able to handle your display needs better than the generic drivers. On a lighter note, the graphic card would be of some use instead of lying around idle. :)

Comment: One thing to keep in mind though. Hybrid technology has not evolved in linux as it has evolved for Windows. So these proprietary drivers might get glitchy a few times(it's rare though). If you encounter too many display issues, then you might as well switch back to Xorg drivers.

Comment: I had a bad experience before using AMD drivers when I installed Ubuntu unity 13.10 my battery life drains so fast, since my laptop experienced over heat.

Comment: if you are having bad experience with AMD drivers, you should better stay with Xorg drivers. But there might have been many official updates since the time you last installed. So why not give the proprietary drivers a try and if there is no improvement in experience you can always revert back to the generic drivers.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thought.
What should I need to choose from additional drivers?
-Using X.org X server AMD/ATI display wrapper from xserver-xorg-video-ati(opensource tested)
-Using Video for the AMD graphics accelerators from fglrx (proprietary)
-Using Video driver for AMD graphics accelerators from fglrx-updates (proprietary)

Comment: You may install `AMD graphics accelerators from fglrx (proprietary)`. For more info visit https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

Comment: If I still have the same issue from my past experience. How can I revert it? Thank you ..

Comment: You can select the radio button besides `AMD/ATI display wrapper from xserver-xorg-video-ati(opensource tested)` and you should be back to the open source alternatives for ATI cards. The reason behind choosing the proprietary ones now is that the `fglrx` is much faster than the generic Xorg RadeonDriver

Comment: My current Graphics driver is Intel® Ivybridge Mobile, so I just I need to choose AMD/ATI display wrapper from xserver-xorg-video-ati(opensource tested) to  revert it?

Comment: As i mentioned earlier, hybrid graphics is a less ventured area. I think installing `fglrx` from additional drivers would let you use the ATI chipset only(i haven't had much handson with AMD cards). I went through the ubuntu documentation and came across the following link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD#Manually_installing_Catalyst_13.4.2C_special_case_for_Intel.2BAC8-AMD_hybrid_graphics . You should give this a try.

Comment: Ill try this link, Im having some trouble since Im newbie in linux, however I highly appreciated this community its really helpful.